# Android Application While Loop Error

Tags: android, while-loop

I've a text file in my partners computer which is hosted on a server. I'm attempting to retrieve all the string values in the text file in my Android application. However, my application doesn't enter the while loop method to read the text file. Is there a way to solve it? My computer is connected to my partners server.

Code for the method.

```
connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v){
         Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable(){
             @Override
             public void run(){
                 //code to do the HTTP request
                 try {
                     URL url = new URL("insert url");//your website link
                     HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                     String line;
                     while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                         result.setText(line);
                     }
                     con.disconnect();
                 } catch(IOException e) {
                     System.out.println("Error");
                 }
             }
        });
        trd.start();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception in the logcat? Like NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: nope,the application has a problem trying to trace my file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)  {

   result.setText(line);

}
```

result can not run in a thread different from the UI THread.
use

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)  {
final String finalLine = line;

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
       result.setText(finalLine);
  }
});
}
```

Comment: I got a "CANNOT REFER TO A NON-FINAL VARIABLE finalLine inside an inner class defined in a different method" error

Comment: Right now,after I do debugging on eclipse,after the bufferedreader line,it immediately jumps to the catch error line. The application did not enter the while loop,what might be the problem?

Comment: are you really using "insert url" ?

Comment: Nope,stackoverflow doesn't allow posting of url so I had to subsitute it with "insert url". The real url is the one I took from the browser which is working.

Comment: have you the internet permission?

Comment: Yeap,I have the permission to access the internet on my application

Comment: Okay,for my emulator it is not working but when I try the application on my android phone it is working.any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 URL url= new URL("insert url");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    StringBuilder result= new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line + "\n");
                }

                TextView.setText(result);
```

Comment: It still doesn't work.My application still cannot trace the file in my partners server

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` fired at the time of `HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();`

You should not perform network operations on the main thread from honeycomb and above versions which leads to this error. Because of it the while loop is never executed.

Use `AsyncTask` instead to perform network operations. Here's a link:  [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/1117338)

Comment: I'm already using a new thread method to run the connection on another thread